# How can I show a string in 2/3 lines with libharu on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, libharu

I have a string which is longer than the width of the place where it has to show up. What I want to do is show the string on 2 or 3 lines.

My code is as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<claimsCount; i++) 
{
    File_Claim *fileClaim = [claimsArray objectAtIndex:i]; 

    [self checkCreateNewPage:font:10.0];

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // if the current category is the same as the previous one then don't write it again
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ([subcategory isEqualToString:fileClaim.subCategoryName]) 
    {
    }
    else
    {
        // hold the old category to check if it is the same
        subcategory = fileClaim.subCategoryName;
        //HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill (_currentPage, 0, 0, 1);
        posY -= PDF_SPACER_Y;
        HPDF_Page_TextOut(_currentPage, PDF_BASE_DATA_LABELS_START_X, posY, [fileClaim.subCategoryName cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]);
    }

    //HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill (_currentPage, 0, 0, 0);
    posY -= PDF_SPACER_Y;

    HPDF_Page_TextOut(_currentPage, PDF_BASE_DATA_LABELS_START_X+15, posY, [fileClaim.name cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut(_currentPage, [self alignRightNumberX:fileClaim.unitPrice:260], posY, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f €",fileClaim.unitPrice] cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut(_currentPage, 320, posY, [[fileClaim getCalcString] cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut(_currentPage, [self alignRightNumberX:fileClaim.totalPrice:483], posY, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f €",fileClaim.totalPrice] cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]);
}
```

And the part where I put my text:

```
 HPDF_Page_TextOut(_currentPage, PDF_BASE_DATA_LABELS_START_X+15, posY, [fileClaim.name cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]);
```

Now this has to come on 2 or 3 lines instead of 1. And I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Lewion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using LibHaru for few days now, and I came across the same question.. I went into writting my own C function to deal with line breaks and multiline support ; and then today I found out that `HPDF_Page_TextRect()` can actually do the job for you! :)

It will automatically wrap up words on multilines in a area defined by a Rectangle and it also returns the number of characters written...